# Solutions of a non-linear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Consider this system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
xy=a\\
x+y=a\\
0\leq x\leq 1\\
0\leq y\leq 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $a\in [0,1]$ is a parameter and $x,y$ are the unknowns.

When $a=0$, $x=0,y=0$ are clearly the solutions of the system. I think that there are no solutions for other values of $a$. Is it enough to show that 
by rewriting the system as
$$
y^2-ay+a=0
$$
and then saying that, for any $a\in (0,1]$, $a^2-4a<0$?

Comment: Yeah, that's good.

Comment: and don't forgett the condition $$0\le y\le 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy=a(a-4)\ge0$$
 is indeed contradictory with

$$0\le xy=a\le 1$$ except for $a=0$.